# Adicionar formatação à descrição de um aplicativo no Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Alguém sabe como "enfeitar" a descrição do aplicativo na play store? Por exemplo colocar "novidades", formatar texto, etc.

Vejam em destaque no exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimentalmente, descobri que você pode utilizar:

- Quebra de Linhas simples são ignoradas;Quebra de Linhas duplas abrem um novo parágrafo;
- Quebra de Linhas simples podem ser forçadas terminando a linha com dois espaços (similar ao Markdown).
- Um conjunto limitado de tags HTML (opcionalmente aninhadas), especialmente:

  - `<b>...</b>` para bold,
  - `<i>...</i>` para itálico,
  - `<u>...</u>` para sublinhado,
  - `<br />` para forçar uma quebra de linha simples
- Uma URL formatada como `http://google.com` aparece como hiperlink.
  (Cuidado quando tentar utilizar uma tag HTML `<a>` com descrição customizada porque isso *não* funciona e quebra a formatação)
- Caracteres HTML especiais são suportados, como `&rarr;` (→), `&trade;` (™) and `&reg;` (®); consulte [esta referencia W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) para a lista completa.
- Caracteres encodados em UTF-8 são suportados, como, €, £, ‘, ’, ★ and ☆.
- Identação não é estritamente possivel, mas utilizando um marcador e um espaço parece razoável (`&#8226;&#8195;` fica "• ").
- Emoji são suportados.

Notas especials referentes as **aplicativos do Google play**:

- Algumas tags HTML funciona apenas no aplicativo:

  - `<blockquote>...</blockquote>` para identar um paragrafo do texto,
  - `<small>...</small>` para um texto for a levemente menor,
  - `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` para super- e subscripts.
  - `<font color="#000000">...</font>` para definir a cor da fonte em codificação HEX.
- Alguns símbolos não aparecem corretamente, como ‣.
- Todas as formatações acima também aparecem corretamente na sessão "What's New".

Notas especias sobre o **site do Google Play**:

- Algumas tags HTML funcionam apenas no website:

  - `<s>...</s>` para rasurado.
- Texto plano aparece na sessão "What's New" ( e a formatação HTML sera mostrada como texto plano);

Retirado do [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746972/1792268)